# getting data from a json array into a table

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to create a filter search for my company's CMS list of articles. I am not sure how to turn the returning JSON data into data for my html table. I have, however, not done this before and am not sure how to iterate through the data.

Here is some dummy output data:

```
[{"articleID":"7298","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"},{"articleID":"7299","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"},{"articleID":"7300","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"},{"articleID":"7301","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"}]
```

Here is the relevant JS code:

```
$.post("link",  { issue: isearch, availability: asearch, type: tsearch }, function(data) {
        var htm =''
        console.log(data);
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            jason = data.getJSONObject(i);
            articleID = jason.articleID;
            title = jason.title;
            issueDate = jason.issueDate;
            htm += '<tr id="news'+articleID+'">'
                +   '<td>'+title+'</td>'
                +   '<td>'+issueDate+'</td>'
                +   '<td><a href="cms/index/addnews/news/'+articleID+'">make top news</a></td>'
                +   '<td><a href="link">view</a></td>'
                +   '<td><a href="cms/news/updatenews/'+articleID+'">update</a></td><td><a href="" class="delete" id="'+articleID+'">delete</a></td>'
                +   '</tr>';
        }
        $('.cms').html(htm);
    });
```

I already tried doing this using data[i].articleID but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: data.getJSONObject is not a function within your dummy data...

Comment: Consider a template (e.g. Handlebars)

Comment: Does `console.log(data);` give you a string or an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data.getJSONObject is not a function.  You just need to change that to `data[i]`

http://jsfiddle.net/A3Srb/

```
EDIT
```

I noticed you said you already tried data[i].  Are you sure that data is the same as the dummy data you have in your example?  Use fiddler or add a console.log(data) to be certain.

Comment: data[i] seems to be getting me into the array but there are two problems.

1) it is showing 'undefined' for everything 2) data.length is returning 3238. It should really be about 30

Comment: yeh data is giving each character so data[i] returns a single character from data. So for some reason it is a string and not an array?

Comment: Ok we are set, I also needed 
    data = JSON.parse(data);
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try this, replace your for statement with an each and use append() rather than html() on your table, html() would just clear it out each time

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var data = [{"articleID":"7298","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"},{"articleID":"7299","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"},{"articleID":"7300","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"},{"articleID":"7301","title":"inbrief","issueDate":"July 2012"}];

    $.each(data, function(key, value){

         htm = '<tr id="news'+data[key].articleID+'">';
            htm+=   '<td>'+data[key].title+'</td>';
            htm+=   '<td>'+data[key].issueDate+'</td>';
            htm+=  '<td><a href="cms/index/addnews/news/'+data[key].articleID+'">make top news</a></td>';
            htm+=   '<td><a href="link">view</a></td>';
            htm+= '<td><a href="cms/news/updatenews/'+data[key].articleID+'">update</a></td><td><a href="" class="delete" id="'+data[key].articleID+'">delete</a></td>';
            htm+=   '</tr>';
            $('.cms').append(htm);
        });


});
```

here is the jsfiddle of the code without the $.post logic, as i did not know what those vars were for isearch ect http://jsfiddle.net/94jXh/

if you would like to make your notation more readable, sub this in for the htm var setting

```
         htm = '<tr id="news'+key.articleID+'">';
            htm+=   '<td>'+key.title+'</td>';
            htm+=   '<td>'+key.issueDate+'</td>';
            htm+=  '<td><a href="cms/index/addnews/news/'+key.articleID+'">make top news</a></td>';
            htm+=   '<td><a href="link">view</a></td>';
            htm+= '<td><a href="cms/news/updatenews/'+key.articleID+'">update</a></td><td><a href="" class="delete" id="'+key.articleID+'">delete</a></td>';
            htm+=   '</tr>';
```

I do however agree with https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/ime-vidas, using a template jquery plugin would work better, i like jsrender https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, I suggest something like this:

```
var articleTemplate = '<tr id="news%1"><td>%2</td><td>%3</td><td><a href="cms/index/addnews/news/%1">make top news</a></td><td><a href="link">view</a></td><td><a href="cms/news/updatenews/%1">update</a></td><td><a href="" class="delete" id="%1">delete</a></td></tr>';//informal template

$.post("link",  { issue: isearch, availability: asearch, type: tsearch }, function(data) {
    var htm = $.map(data, function(a, i) {
        return articleTemplate.replace(/%1/g, a.articleID).replace('%2', a.title).replace('%3', a.issueDate);
    });
    $('.cms').html(htm.join(''));
});
```

This minimises the number of partial strings involved in building `htm` and hence imposes less load on the client memory and gives Garbage Collection less work to do.

If you do a lot of other templating then consider something like Moustache or Handlebars, otherwise the informal approach above is fine (and very efficient).